# spring boot multiple module configuration

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, yaml, multi-module

I am currently refactoring a Spring-Boot application running v1.5.1.Release, built with Maven. I'm trying to refactor the application to simplify the deployment process for our DevOps team.

Previously the application was configured with library artifacts or 'clients' that were pulled into the project as maven dependencies/jars from our Artifactory server. Our group owns the dependencies, which are not currently used by any other applications. The previous project structure looked like this:

```
[Root package]
Client
|-src/main
|---java.com.company.group.app.client
|----config
|----[...]
|----service
|---resources
|----config
|-----application.yml
|-----application-test.yaml
|-----[...]
|+pom.xml
|-test/main
|---java.com.company.group.app.client
|----[...]
Service
|-src/main
|---java.com.company.group.app.service
|----app
|----[...]
|---Application.java (main spring-boot method)
|+pom.xml
parent-pom.xml
```

The structure I am working on will be a mono-repo with dependent projects as modules listed in the parent pom. i.e.

```
[root-package]
Client
|-src/main
|---java.com.company.group.app.client
|----config
|----[...]
|----service
|---resources
|----config
|-----application.yml
|-----application-test.yaml
|-----[...]
|+pom.xml
|-test/main
|---java.com.company.group.app.client
|----[...]
Service
|-src/main
|---java.com.company.group.app.service
|----app
|----[...]
|---Application.java (main spring-boot method)
|+pom.xml
Module1
|-src/main
|---java.com.company.group.app.module1
|----[...etc]
|+pom.xml
Module2
|-src/main
|---java.com.company.group.app.module2
|----[...etc]
|+pom.xml
Module3
|-src/main
|---java.com.company.group.app.module3
|----[...etc]
|+pom.xml
|parent-pom.xml
```

So far, this approach has been working. I am use component scanning on the base package in the Main method to bring components from sub-modules into the app context.

The issue I am having is that configuration defined in a yaml file in the 'service' module is not being picked up at run-time. The spring-boot main method lives in this same directory.

My question is, do I need to move my Main method outside of the service package into the root of the project or create a wrapper app? Or is there a reason Spring would not be able to use a single yaml for multiple components? There are configurations for each sub-module in one yaml file, and this was working when the modules were pulled in as library dependencies.

I've tried searching SO but no questions seem to touch my specific issue.